# Split a file into several files

Tags: c++, c

I have a big file (16 Gb) with millions of records. Each record has a 20 bytes structure.

Now, I need to split this file into several temporary, new files (about 100 Mb each) and at the same time to keep this structure intact (not to cut in the middle of 20 bytes).

What is the best algorithm to calculate the size for new files?

Comment: Depends. What is the format of your file? Which language — C or C++? Pick _one_.

Comment: `system("split -b " + std::to_string((100ul << 20)/20*20) + " '" + filename + "'");` (why c++)

Answer (score 3):

If each record is always 20 bytes, you will fit exactly 5242880 records in a 100 MB (100 * 1024 * 1024) file.

So it should be pretty obvious how to do this, there's no risk of damaging a record as long as you always read and write multiples of 20 bytes at a time. Since your desired slice size of 100 MB is such a multiple, use that. If you're doing this on a desktop-class PC or something, an I/O buffer of 100 MB is pretty large but not extreme.

So, you're going to do something like this:

```
bool chunkify(const char *filename, size_t chunkSize)
{
  void *buffer = malloc(chunkSize);
  FILE *in;
  bool ok = true;

  if (buffer == NULL)
    return false;

  if ((fin = fopen(filename, "rb")) != NULL)
  {
    size_t got;
    unsigned int count = 0;

    while(ok && (got = fread(buffer, 1, chunkSize, fin)) > 0)
    {
      FILE *fout;
      char outname[1024];
      snprintf(outname, sizeof outname, "%s-%u", filename, count++);
      if ((fout = fopen(outname, "wb")) != NULL)
      {
        ok &= fwrite(buffer, got, 1, fout);
        fclose(fout);
      }
    }
    fclose(fin);
  }
  free(buffer);
  return ok;
}
```

Note: the above is untested semi-complicated I/O code meant as a starting point only. It will likely have bugs for you to find.

Comment: Just to expand a little: Write 100MB files with 20 byte block size. This will take forever though, so maybe use multiples of 20 bytes? In bash terms - `dd if=sourceFile of=destFile bs=20 count=5242880`

Comment: I put 16 GB as an exemple. The final size will change.<br> I need all this for external sorting.. to create chunks..

Comment: @AlexK The size of the input doesn't matter, you're going to do the exact same thing if it's 20 bytes as if it's 16 GB.

Comment: @AlexK Feel free to Accept the answer if you like it. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Uh ... Not sure what to say. I think it's confusing to get praise but not the accept.

Comment: BTW please note that I'm not trying to compete with my own answer: I just felt like a summary was useful. I'm not expecting it to "beat" yours and so that's not what my conversation about accepts is about! :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure ... My experience is that many new users don't know about the Accept functionality (which is why they post a supportive comment instead) and that irks me. Didn't mean to offend.

Answer (score 2):

The best algorithm is *arithmetic*!

The closest multiple of 20 byte records to 100MB is 5,242,880 records, and in fact comes to *exactly* 100MB.

So you can simply chop up your file into 100MB chunks and be done with it.